# Writing an image out to a file in a cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a graphics editing cocoa app on Mac OSX that produces 32 by 32 square bitmaps, I need to programatically (I cannot use the interface builder at all) output this image to either a .jpg or .png.  Can anyone link me to some good resources on how I might accomplish this task?

Comment: We need to know more. How are you storing this data internally at present? Are you on Mac OS X or iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an `NSBitmapImageRep` from the image, that can produce PNG and JPEG.  See `representationUsingType:properties:`

Comment: But how do you get an NSBitImageRep from an NSImage?

Answer (score 2):

I know you said jpeg or png, but you could use `NSImage`'s [TIFFRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/TIFFRepresentation) method. It returns an instance of `NSData`. So doing something along the lines of

```
[[yourImageInstance TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:@"/path/to/file.tiff" atomically:NO];
```

would write that TIFF image to file. I do not think `NSImage` has any built-in way of getting the data in png or jpeg form.

**Edit**

Did a quick Google and found [this link](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSImage) with info on saving PNG data instead of TIFF data. Seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Having an UIImage called image:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *tmpPathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tempImage.jpg", tempPath]];
[imageData writeToFile:tmpPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **PhotoshopFramework** for iPhone (https://sourceforge.net/projects/photoshopframew/). Have very convenient methods to save images to disk:

```
/// Save as JPG File with High Quality.
-(BOOL)saveAsJPGFile:(NSString*)anFileName;

/// Save as JPG File with User Defined Quality.
-(BOOL)saveAsJPGFile:(NSString*)anFileName compressionQuality:(CGFloat)quality;

/// Save as PNG File.
-(BOOL)saveAsPNGFile:(NSString*)anFileName;
```